# How can i use strong params to send object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can i allow only certains fields for the hash using strong params?

```
def store_params
        params.require(:store)
              .permit(section: [:value])
end
```

i am testing like this:

```
it 'test1' do
        payload = {
          section: {
            value: 'new value'
          }
        }
        put "/api/#{id}/sections/#{section['id']}", params: payload
```

always iam getting this error:

```
{"error"=>"param is missing or the value is empty: section"}
```

note: this one should not be allowed:

```
payload = {
          section: {
            other_value: 'other value'
          }
        }
```

Comment: Actually, what does any of this have to do with JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Your test's payload strucutre doesn't match your controllers parameter structure

You have not indicated which one of the two is canonical, but assuming you're not doing TDD, try changing your test to:

```rb
it 'test1' do
  payload = { 
    store: { 
      section: {
        value: 'new value' # Should be accepted
        other_value: 'illegal stuff' # Should be rejected
      }
    }
  }

  # TODO: Use rails helpers, `put api_section_path(id, section.id)`
  put "/api/#{id}/sections/#{section['id']}", params: payload
  
  expect(section.reload.value).to eq('new value')
  expect(section.other_value).to eq('initial unchanged value')
end
```

Comment: but i should send like this payload = { 
      section: {
        value: 'new value' # Should be accepted
        other_value: 'illegal stuff' # Should be rejected
      }
  }

Comment: Ah, so you _are_ doing it TDD-style. In that case, remove `store` from your params in your controller.